# Display List of Friends of Array

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry for including so much in here I just do not know where to begin as I am new to Java and I am lost on how to Display an Entire List of Friends once I have inputed them into the array.  **I need to use a for loop to do this.**

Answer (score 3):

Add a `toString` method to your `Friend` class like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Friend [firstName=" + firstName + ", firstAge=" + firstAge + "]";
}
```

So when you call `System.out.println()` you will get a human readable format and not the hashcode.

I would also suggest you move the line :`System.out.println("\nYou have added the following friends:");` out of the for loop.

You can remove the entry from the list like:

```
public void removeFriend()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter Name of person you would like to remove: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    Iterator<Friend> it = friendList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Friend f = it.next();
        if(f.getName().equals(name)){
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked and I appreciate the advice of moving the print statement out of the loop.  Now I can not seem to remove and friends from the list.  Here is my code that I currently have for adding friends and removing friends...@ManishKothari

Comment: @gan212 I have added the code to remove objects from the friendList.